# IP-address from sk_buff

Tags: c, linux-kernel, netfilter

I am writing a kernel module which registers a netfilter hook. I am trying to get the ip address of the caller by using the `sk_buff->saddr` member. Is there a way I can get the IP in human readable i.e. x.x.x.x format?

I found the function `inet_ntop()` but it doesn't seem to be available in kernel headers. How do I convert \xC0\xA8\x00\x01 to 192.168.0.1 ?

Comment: inet_ntop() and its brother inet_pton() are actually in arpa/inet.h , I'm looking for the kernel implementations now.

Comment: ummm, netfilter's log target must do this... I'd look there.

Comment: &Rohit: to be honest, if you don't know how to format bytes in a string like that, you probably shouldn't be writing a kernel module. Try some user space stuff first.

Comment: &Evan: I agree but there was not much I could do about it. Baptism by fire is how I look at it.

Comment: @EvanTeran that's why there is a concept called reusability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two macros defined in include/linux/kernel.h

NIPQUAD for ipv4 addresses and NIP6 for ipv6 addresses.

```
#define NIPQUAD(addr) \
    ((unsigned char *)&addr)[0], \
    ((unsigned char *)&addr)[1], \
    ((unsigned char *)&addr)[2], \
    ((unsigned char *)&addr)[3]

#define NIP6(addr) \
    ntohs((addr).s6_addr16[0]), \
    ntohs((addr).s6_addr16[1]), \
    ntohs((addr).s6_addr16[2]), \
    ntohs((addr).s6_addr16[3]), \
    ntohs((addr).s6_addr16[4]), \
    ntohs((addr).s6_addr16[5]), \
    ntohs((addr).s6_addr16[6]), \
    ntohs((addr).s6_addr16[7])
```

There are ample examples in the kernel sources that make use of these to print ip addresses in human-readable format. For instance:

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "Received packet from source address: %d.%d.%d.%d!\n",NIPQUAD(iph->saddr));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ran across this now. For the benefit of others who may stumble across this, `NIPQUAD` has been ellimated after 2.6.38. Use `%pI4` instead

Comment: Came across this later. There is now `in4_pton()` in /net/core/utils.c

Comment: @BonBon: `in4_pton()` does the reverse.

Answer (score 17):

You should use the %pI4 extended format specifiers provided by printk():

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "IP addres = %pI4\n", &local_ip);
```

Answer (score 3):

printk can handle this directly:

IPv4 addresses:

```
%pI4    1.2.3.4
%pi4    001.002.003.004
%p[Ii]4[hnbl]

For printing IPv4 dot-separated decimal addresses. The 'I4' and 'i4'
specifiers result in a printed address with ('i4') or without ('I4')
leading zeros.

The additional 'h', 'n', 'b', and 'l' specifiers are used to specify
host, network, big or little endian order addresses respectively. Where
no specifier is provided the default network/big endian order is used.

Passed by reference.
```

IPv6 addresses:

```
%pI6    0001:0002:0003:0004:0005:0006:0007:0008
%pi6    00010002000300040005000600070008
%pI6c   1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8

For printing IPv6 network-order 16-bit hex addresses. The 'I6' and 'i6'
specifiers result in a printed address with ('I6') or without ('i6')
colon-separators. Leading zeros are always used.

The additional 'c' specifier can be used with the 'I' specifier to
print a compressed IPv6 address as described by
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952

Passed by reference.
```

Reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt

Answer (score 2):

Simple. The IP address in "x.x.x.x" format is called dotted-quad for a reason. Each number represents a byte, for a total of 4 bytes in your address.

So, with the 4 byte address, you would simply print the decimal value of each byte.

Quick and dirty example (replace printf with your output function of choice):

```
unsigned char *addr = (unsigned char*)sk_buff->addr;
printf("%d.%d.%d.%d", addr[0], addr[1], addr[2], addr[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol.html) to convert each piece to it's integer form.

Comment: I'm almost positive that a macro exists which does just that, I just can't find it ATM.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Convinience union to __be32 to ip address  */
union ip_address {
    u8 a[4];
    __be32 saddr;
};
```

IP Address could be obtained a[0].a[1].a[2].a[3]