# Converting network byte order IP to host byte order with ip4 format in kernel module

Tags: c, networking, module, linux-kernel, ip-address

I am writing a kernel module in Arch Linux with [c](/questions/tagged/c) language. I want to convert the network IP to host IP with ip4 format: 127.0.0.1

I know it is possible in user program to use these functions:

```
inetntoa()
ntohs()
ntohl()
```

I tried to include the *`socket.h`*, *`in.h`*, etc and use the below functions, but none of them worked for me.

So in kernel module I don't have access to this functions.
Is there in kernel module a replacement for this functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have access to `ntohl()` and friends. Just `#include <linux/byteorder/generic.h>`.
Use it as usual:

```
__le32 le_ipaddr = ntohl(be_ipaddr); /* to flip big-endian IP to little-endian */
```

---

Also you can print IPv4 address as you want without any difficulties through the special format specifier `%pI4` in `printk()` e.g. such way:

```
__be32 ipaddr /*= gain from somewhere IP in network byte order (__be32 means big endian)*/;
printk(KERN_INFO "Got IP: %pI4\n", &ipaddr); /* in network byte order */
printk(KERN_INFO "Got IP: %pI4h\n", &ipaddr); /* in host byte order */
```

Read also:

[IP-address from sk_buff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584713/ip-address-from-sk-buff)

[How to get printk format specifiers right](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt) (from Kernel.org):

> Passed by reference.
>
> IPv4 addresses
>
> ==============
>
> ::
>
> %pI4    1.2.3.4
>
> %pi4    001.002.003.004
>
> ...
>
> The additional `h`, `n`, `b`, and `l` specifiers are used to
>   specify host, network, big or little endian order addresses
>   respectively. Where no specifier is provided the default network/big
>   endian order is used.

...

> Passed by reference.
>
> IPv6 addresses
>
> ==============
>
> ::
>
> %pI6   0001:0002:0003:0004:0005:0006:0007:0008
>
> %pi6   00010002000300040005000600070008
>
> %pI6c  1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8

---

P.S. you can search the functions you need in Linux kernel sources, e.g. on this site: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/

Answer (score -1):

If by "network IP" you mean a 32-bit big-endian integer representing a IPv4 that you wish to convert to a dotted-decimal string representation, then it can be done with `sprintf()`.

```
int32_t ipv4 = 1234567890; // random example

unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)&ipv4;
char ipstr[16];
sprintf(ipstr, "%d.%d.%d.%d", ptr[0], ptr[1],  ptr[2],  ptr[3]);
```

`ipstr` will contain the string with the IP address.

Comment: This might invoke UB or is at least dependent on the endianess of the target architecture; a better solution is to use arithmetics to divide the integer into octets.

Comment: @Ctx Network is big-endian across architectures, there's no risk of that. That's why the functions `htons()`, `htonl()`, `ntohs()` and `ntohl()` exist, they convert between "host endianess" to "network endianess", which is big-endian. If the host is already big-endian, they do nothing.

Comment: If the ipv4 is represented as an integer and stored in an integer variable, it _is_ dependent on the endianess of the machine. Integer representations of IPs are well defined and platform independent, 127.0.0.1 is for example 2130706433. Use this instead of your 1234567890 and compile your program big and little endian, you will get different results.

Comment: @Ctx If it is coming from the socket library, it is not. Little-endian machines will simply interpret it wrong. It is always stored in network endianess (big endian).

Comment: Sorry, you are plain wrong here. Try "telnet 2130706433" on a recent unix box to open a connection to localhost. If you do `int32_t ipv4 = 2130806433` and use your method above to convert it to dotted-quad notation you get "1.0.0.127" or "127.0.0.1", dependent on the machine endianess. Technically, you are invoking undefined behaviour for violating the strict-aliasing rule, so converting it this way is an ill advice in any case.

Comment: That's because this number is coming from user interface and has to be converted to network format with `htonl()` to make any sense to the sockets library. **It is always big-endinan in the socket library!**

Comment: Endianess is a feature of the cpu architecture, not of a library. You are mixing up things and are confusing yourself or others with imprecise terminology. The term "a 32-bit big-endian integer" is completely misleading, an integer is neither big- or little-endian, but can be _stored_ in memory big- or little endian.

Comment: @Ctx It does not matter what endianess the CPU understands, this information is for networking and the IP protocol uses big-endian therefore all information in the networking headers must use big-endian, the IP address, port, checksums, everything has to be in big-endian and that's what the functions `htons()` and associates are there for. If you read a 32-bit IP from any socket structure from the socket.h library, it is immediately in big-endian regardless of architecture,  you'd have to convert it with `ntohl()` to bring it to your host endianess.

Comment: But you didn't do that in your example, you hard-coded an ipv4 "1234567890" which represents "73.150.2.210", but will be decoded wrong as "210.2.150.73" on most platforms. Why is this so hard to understand? And apart from that, it still is UB and should not be done at all this way. Perhaps you should start fixing your answer instead of trying to discuss its shortcomings away.

Comment: @Ctx I explicitly stated it's a random example, not a specific IP, I don't care what address it's in there I merely initialized the variable with garbage.